# Is there right way to store resolved promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Right now almost every node package has callback api. What if I'm writing wrapper around it, ORM for instance:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const mongo = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));

class ORM {
  constructor(mongoUrl) {
    this.db = mongo.connectAsync(mongoUrl);
  }

  collection(name) {
    return this.db.then((db) => {
      return db.collectionAsync(name);
    });
  }
}
```

Is this right way?

Comment: Did  you try it?  The general idea seems like it could work.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [codereview.SE]

Comment: This would make a good Code Review question, if you have a working implementation that can be reviewed.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are recommending code-review. OP is asking if storing promises is acceptable.

Comment: What does this have to do with "storing resolved promises"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a promise is just a proxy for a value representing value + time.

What you're doing is perfectly fine. **It's OK to store promises,** in fact it's generally *better* to store promises and not the values they hold because that way you get a lot less race conditions.

The only issue with what you're doing is error handling. Let's say the connection failed - you're not reacting to it or detecting it until a request is actually made to the database which doesn't make too much sense. You should decide how you want to act to a connection failure in the constructor and deal with it.

If you want to *explicitly suppress* unhandled rejections detected you can do:

```
this.db = mongo.connectAsync(mongoUrl);
this.db.catch(() => {});
```

Although personally I recommend against it, you should perhaps have reconnect logic, and maybe even crash the server if multiple reconnection attempts failed.